# Javascript - Login with Facebook, display user's profile picture after logged in successfully

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am making a Facebook Quiz app. Which lets the user log in with Facebook. I'm trying to display User's profile picture automatically without having to click on "Get Info" but really it kept crashing the code and it the login button stops working. Currently, it works. The user logs in then to display the profile picture, the user has to click "Get Info" button and it will display the user's profile picture. **I don't want the "get info" button**, I want the profile picture to be automatically displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="status"></div>
   <div id="lgnbtn">
      <button onclick="login()" id="login">Login with Facebook</button>
   </div>
<button onclick="getInfo()" id="getInfo">Get Info</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
// initialize and setup facebook js sdk
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
              appId      : '1036296558220017',
              xfbml      : true,
              version    : 'v2.5'
            });

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
                    document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.'
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook.';
                }
            });
        };
        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        // login with facebook with extra permissions
        function login() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
                    document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.'
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook.';
                }
            }, {scope: 'email'});
        }

    // getting basic user info
        function getInfo() {
                FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,picture.width(150).height(150)'}, function(response) {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke `getInfo();` in `FB.login` success handler.

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId: '1034762986580727',
    xfbml: true,
    version: 'v2.5'
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
      document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.'
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook.';
    }
  });
};
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {
    return;
  }
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// login with facebook with extra permissions
function login() {
  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are connected.';
      document.getElementById('login').style.visibility = 'hidden';
      getInfo(); // Invoke it here
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'We are not logged in.'
    } else {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'You are not logged into Facebook.';
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'email'
  });
}

// getting basic user info
function getInfo() {
  FB.api('/me', 'GET', {
    fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,picture.width(150).height(150)'
  }, function(response) {
    console.log(response);//Check the response in console
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="lgnbtn">
  <button onclick="login()" id="login">Login with Facebook</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again. Could you help me display the user's name?

Comment: I tried adding this `$request = (new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'GET', '/me/?fields=friends,id,name,birthday,email,picture,gender,location,address,email,hometown'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();   
` to my code although, it did not work.

Comment: Did you check _`response` in console_ ?

Comment: Let's move this to chat please, I'll send you the whole console report

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: login is not a function` im getting this

Comment: Yes!!! It worked!! Sorry for confusing you but I am asking you about a different thing. I want to display the user's name under the picture. `$request = (new FacebookRequest($this->session, 'GET', '/me/?fields=friends,id,name,birthday,email,picture,gender,location,address,emai‌​l,hometown'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();` When I implement this code. The login stops working.

Comment: Why do you need PHP in this ?

Comment: Perfect. It's working. The console showed the basic info about my facebook. First name, last name, id, full name.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: How could you display it with the image?

Comment: Display it with image ? What ?

Comment: Right now, when I log in. Only the image shows... Is it possible to show the name as well?

Comment: You have a object of the user..Do whatever you want to with that object...`innerHTML` or alert or anything....

Comment: I'm confused. I don't know how. Whatever I tried adding crashed the app

Comment: You do have a div for `status` hence you are `innerHTML` image in that `DIV`.. Instead of jumping in complex things..Go through the basics of DOM manipulations...